# Closing tags red in Adobe brackets

Tags: html

I've included a screen shot rather than code for obvious reasons. I'm having trouble figuring out why the closing tags are turning red and I'm  not sure if it's something really simple that I'm overlooking. I think it's something to do with the html element.

screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see the meta, head and html closing tags are all read and I'm not sure why. They were fine before I added the lang=en-gb and utf-8 parts. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/nu/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove `</meta>` tag. `<meta>` doesn't need closing tag.

Comment: "dont need" — It's forbidden, not optional.

Answer (score 0):

`meta` element is a self-closing element. It should be written like this:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
 ...
```

Edit: change `/>` to `>` per @Quentin.

Comment: There's no need to add the `/` silliness.

Comment: I usually put it in there to make it less ambiguous. Without it, someone new to HTML might expect there to be a closing tag somewhere.

Comment: @Quentin Out of pure curiosity, since you have such a large grasp on web development, do you put closing tags on `<p>` and `<li>` even though they aren't necessary? Is that silliness as well?

Comment: @Quantastical — I tend not to. For list items in particular, end tags often harm readability.

Comment: Thanks. I guess, to your point, any way to shave characters should yield faster response times. Appreciate your comments.

Comment: @Quantastical re. your recently deleted q, I got an error in my console. But if you change var $myElement = $('#my-element'); (with single quotes) to var $myElement = $("#my-element"); (double quotes) the error goes away..

Comment: Thanks @RachelGallen. My implementation has a bit more to it than that simple example which is probably why it is triggering. I tried swapping out single-quotes for doubles in my code and it still triggered the error. I will research this a bit more, but I'm not overly concerned anymore because it seems like it might just be related to me and my Dashlane installation. Again, thanks a lot for trying to help me.

Comment: @Quantastical no problem, but damn, i thought i'd solved it! :(